# AngularJS - Custom common directive validation for all fields in a row

Tags: angularjs, validation, angular-directive

I am trying to implement custom validation to check user typed entry is valid or not.

EX: Existing row
ORIG    DEST   DESK    REGION
HYD     MAS     20         34

Scenario's:
1)When user enter new row with same values i need to show validation error.
2)When user enter same orig, dest and region with different desk then also i need to validation error.

I have created custom validation which will check current row with all rows in list and return false if any scenario found.

I need to call this directive on any value change of ORIG or DEST or DESK or REGION and show error message at single place.

I tried with giving directive for all fields, but getting error for every filed not common.

Is there any possibility to do this?

HTML:

```
<form novalidate id="ODDRForm" name="ODDRForm">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>                                                                    
            <th >
                <span>ORIG</span>
            </th>
            <th >
                <span>DEST</span>
            </th>
            <th >
                <span>DESK</span>
            </th>
            <th >
                <span>REGION</span>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody class="tbody_border_bottom">
    <tr ng-repeat="row in List" ng-form="rowForm">
        <td >
            <input check-duplicate type="text" name="origin" ng-model="row.orig" required /><br/>
            <div ng-messages="rowForm.orig.$error" ng-if="ODDRForm.$submitted || rowForm.orig.$touched">
                <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                <span ng-message="checkDuplicate">Not a valid entry</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <input check-duplicate type="text" name="dest" ng-model="row.dest" required /><br/>
            <div ng-messages="rowForm.dest.$error" ng-if="ODDRForm.$submitted || rowForm.dest.$touched">
                <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                <span ng-message="checkDuplicate">Not a valid entry</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <input check-duplicate type="text" name="desk" ng-model="row.desk" required /><br/>
            <div ng-messages="rowForm.desk.$error" ng-if="ODDRForm.$submitted || rowForm.desk.$touched">
                <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                <span ng-message="checkDuplicate">Not a valid entry</span>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td >
            <input check-duplicate type="text" name="region" ng-model="row.region" required /><br/>
            <div ng-messages="rowForm.region.$error" ng-if="ODDRForm.$submitted || rowForm.region.$touched">
                <span ng-message="required">Required</span>
                <span ng-message="checkDuplicate">Not a valid entry</span>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
app.directive('checkDuplicate', [ '$http', function($http) {
return {
    require : '^ngModel',
    link : function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        var bool = true;
        ngModel.$parsers.push(function(value) {
            for(var i in scope.List) {
                if(scope.List[i].orig == scope.row.orig && scope.List[i].dest == scope.row.dest 
                && scope.List[i].desk == scope.row.desk && scope.List[i].region == scope.row.region
                && scope.List[i].$$hashkey != scope.row.$$hashkey) {
                    bool = false;
                }
            }

            ngModel.$setValidity('checkDuplicate', bool);
            return value;
        })
    },
}
```

} ]);

Answer (score 0):

In your case there is no reason to add directives, you can just watch model changes and validate, give me the sample code I can show you how